# Is it efficient to use epoll with devices (/dev/event/...)?

Tags: linux, event-handling, linux-device-driver, epoll, uinput

I am working on a *monothreaded* process applet which creates a proxy virtual device (more precisely a virtual *Xbox 360* pad); I do manage to create it with the [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) interface, I set it up properly and it works just fine.

In order to feed commands to this *virtual device*, I read events from another *real* interface (in this case a *PS3* pad), and I open the *real device* file with these flags:

```
fd = open("/dev/input/event22", O_RDONLY); // open the PS3 pad
```

The main loop is something like (minus error checking):

```
while(run) {
    input_event ev = {0};
    read(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));
    // convert from PS3 --> Xbox 360
    convert(ev);
    // write to the new virtual pad
    write(fd_virtual, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));
}
```

As you can imagine the `read(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));` is a blocking call and I would like to have a sort of timeout to cycle through the loop and check for other events/execute other code.

For these reasons I am thinking of encapsulating that `read(fd...` call inside an [epoll](https://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll) loop, so I can also have a timeout.

Question is, would it be efficient to have it done this way?
By virtue of using [epoll_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait), am I introducing additional delays to the current loop, thus delays in responsiveness of the *virtual pad*?

Answer (score 0):

> By virtue of using epoll_wait, am I introducing additional delays to the current loop, thus delays in responsiveness of the virtual pad?

Yes, you sure do.

> would it be efficient to have it done this way?

I'm sure yes, but that very much depends on your definition of "efficient".

What we're talking about here is a human input device. What we care mostly when dealing with HIDs is latency, it shouldn't lag, the reaction on the keypress should be instant. What is "instant" for a human being? There is a nice [discussion there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536300/), but one argument that I like most is that on a high-level athletics competition you'd be [disqualified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_start) for starting in less than 100 ms after the signal.

But that 100 ms is a time budget to make whole processing of the input signal, from key press to some perceivable changes in the game. [Wikipedia page on input lag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_lag) has some numbers on how this budget is usually spent.

Anyway, I think 1 ms is absolutely safe overhead you can add with your proxy and no one will notice, let's say that's our goal for maximum latency (as in definition of "efficient").

So, let's assume that you're satisfied with the response time from your current code. What changes when you add an `epoll()` call? Basically, you're adding some time for another syscall to be made, because now instead of one syscall to get the value you're making two. So potentially it's about two times slower than your original code (let's forget about difference in processing time for different syscalls for the moment). But is it really that bad?

To answer that question we need to have some estimate of what a syscall overhead is. If we're too lazy to measure it ourselves, we can use some [numbers from 20 years ago](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/approximate_overhead_of_system_calls9?lang=ru), some [numbers from people that care about syscalls](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chensm/Big_Data_reading_group/papers/flexsc-osdi10.pdf), some [IPC numbers from microkernel guys (they always care)](http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp13/papers/p133-elphinstone.pdf), some [random numbers from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41783404/165063) or [just ask Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8247379/165063) and settle around something microsecond-level as a safe assumption.

So the question boils down to whether adding some (let's even say 10) microseconds is noticable within your millisecond (as in 1000 µs) time budget. I think it's not.

There is just one little possible problem, when you're to go from "just adding `epoll()`" to

> cycle through the loop and check for other events/execute other code.

You need to be careful to stay within your time budget for these loops and checks. But then again 1 ms is probably more than enough for you here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, but unfortunately this is very _generalist_ answer. I'm referring to joypads, you can imagine it's about gaming. Usually folks do play with 100Hz, which implies that if the _epoll_ call may add maybe _x_ more msec (according to the answer from Rich - "up to the order of milliseconds for IO"), then it does make a difference, and I'm looking for precise answers. If I have to measure it myself, I might aswell do it (but what's the point of the bounty?).

Comment: What Rich referring to is that I/O can differ in size and that it can take time to transfer to/from the device. Your I/O is your `read()` and `write()` with just some bytes to transfer from already filled buffer to the buffer of your virtual device, in your particular case I bet you won't see any milliseconds for reads and writes. And I can't see any way for `epoll()` to go into ms range (just because of its nature), it would be exactly that --- some µs. Also, take a closer look at FlexSC paper from my links, they count things in cycles, but that's easily converted to some time values.